# Can I use external TMS service as a store in Geoserver?

Tags: geoserver, wms, wmts, tile-map-service

I have GeoServer hosted on my server and I want to connect a store so that I can serve layers from there. I am aware that I can connect external WMS source to geoserver, but not sure how to connect TMS.

e.g. of TMS Service
https://sit-geonetwork.geoplatform.info/geonetwork/srv/eng/catalog.search#/metadata/ca63648a-2330-5df7-b644-e2a53832acda

Comment: The metadata record linked to doesn't seem to describe any TMS.   The cited services for the dataset are either ArcGIS bespoke or WMS services.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently, you can only cascade WMS and WMTS services. TMS is an old and not very well supported "standard" so there is no easy way to discover the extents and number of tiles.

It would be possible to extend the existing WMTS cascading code to support TMS but it would require some coding or [sponsorship](http://geoserver.org/support/) to make it happen.