How to connect to OpenStreetMap WMTServer
I'm trying to connect to OSM, via the URL "https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", with GeoTools WMTS (gt-wmts-28.0.jar).
I can connect to a WebMapServer, but now I'd like to add WebMapTile functionallity.
As I understand, according to ( https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Raster_tile_providers ), it should be free to use.
What can be wrong?
This is the code i use:
try {
        URL url = new URL("https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png");
        wmts = new WebMapTileServer(url);
        
    } catch (IOException | ServiceException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

This is the stack trace;
    apr. 15, 2024 8:07:30 FM org.geotools.data.ows.AbstractOpenWebService internalIssueRequest
ALLVARLIG: Failed to execute request https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?REQUEST=GetCapabilities&VERSION=1.0.0&SERVICE=WMTS
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?REQUEST=GetCapabilities&VERSION=1.0.0&SERVICE=WMTS
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1924)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1520)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
    at org.geotools.http.SimpleHttpClient$SimpleHTTPResponse.<init>(SimpleHttpClient.java:209)
    at org.geotools.http.SimpleHttpClient.get(SimpleHttpClient.java:136)
    at org.geotools.http.SimpleHttpClient.get(SimpleHttpClient.java:105)
    at org.geotools.data.ows.AbstractOpenWebService.internalIssueRequest(AbstractOpenWebService.java:455)
    at org.geotools.data.ows.AbstractOpenWebService.issueRequest(AbstractOpenWebService.java:489)
    at org.geotools.data.ows.AbstractOpenWebService.negotiateVersion(AbstractOpenWebService.java:287)
    at org.geotools.data.ows.AbstractOpenWebService.<init>(AbstractOpenWebService.java:124)
    at org.geotools.data.ows.AbstractOpenWebService.<init>(AbstractOpenWebService.java:97)
    at org.geotools.data.ows.AbstractOpenWebService.<init>(AbstractOpenWebService.java:88)
    at org.geotools.data.ows.AbstractOpenWebService.<init>(AbstractOpenWebService.java:77)
    at org.geotools.ows.wmts.WebMapTileServer.<init>(WebMapTileServer.java:151)
    at org.geotools.jdbcconnection.mapview.WMTSHandler.<init>(WMTSHandler.java:37)
    at org.geotools.jdbcconnection.mapview.MapView.addargs(MapView.java:2688)
    at org.geotools.jdbcconnection.mapview.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:356)
    at org.geotools.jdbcconnection.MainDialog$169.actionPerformed(MainDialog.java:3683)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:297)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6635)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6400)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5011)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4843)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4547)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4843)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.geotools.jdbcconnection.mapview.WMTSHandler.<init>(WMTSHandler.java:43)
    at org.geotools.jdbcconnection.mapview.MapView.addargs(MapView.java:2688)
    at org.geotools.jdbcconnection.mapview.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:356)
    at org.geotools.jdbcconnection.MainDialog$169.actionPerformed(MainDialog.java:3683)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:297)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6635)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6400)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5011)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4843)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4547)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4843)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)


That is not a WMTS service at all. It is closer to TMS, but GeoServer does not support cascading TMS either https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/385651/can-i-use-external-tms-service-as-a-store-in-geoserver.

It could do if someone wrote some code to do it

You need to provide a getCapabilies endpoint rather than the zxy template, GeoTools expects to read the template URL from the capabilities response.
BUT since OSM is not actually a WMTS service it won't provide you with a getCapabilities endpoint. So you will need to use the OSMService which allows you to do something like:
final TileService service = new OSMService("OSM", "http://tile.openstreetmap.org/");
final Tile tile = new OSMTile(2166, 1189, new WebMercatorZoomLevel(12), service);
final BufferedImage image = tile.getBufferedImage();

See the test cases in the gt-tile-client module.

Ok, I will then open a Tile OSM thread.
